# Why is $\frac{a-ar^n}{1-r}$ always an integer when $a$, $r$ (except $1$), and (positive) $n$ are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a_1$ and $r$ are integers, explain why the value of $\dfrac{a_1-a_1r^n}{1-r}$ must also be an integer.

Does anyone have any ideas to rigorously explain/prove it? I can't really think of anything. (Also this is besides when $r=1$ of course.)

EDIT: $n$ is any positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n is a positive integer, then the expression $r^n - 1$ can be factored:

$r^n - 1 = (r - 1)(r^{n-1} + r^{n-2} + ...  + r^2 + r  + 1)$

Therefore: $\frac{a_1-a_1r^n}{1-r} = \frac{a_1r^n-a_1}{r-1}=a_1(r^{n-1} + r^{n-2} + ...  + r^2 + r  + 1)$

Comment: Why can't n be equal to 1?

Comment: I guess it can, but it doesn't really tell you anything useful as the equation just simplifies down to r - 1 = r - 1. But for the sake of completeness, I edited my answer since it does work.

Comment: Thanks. It confused me slightly.

Answer (score 6):

From geometric formula,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}r^i=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Hence the expression is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{a_1-a_1r^n}{1-r}=a_1(1+r+r^2+....+r^{n-1})$$

if $r \ne 1.$

Try a proof by induction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the induction part?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this geometric progrssion

$a_1,a_1r,a_1r^2,a_1r^3......a_1r^{n-1}$

As $a_1$ and $r$ are integers, sum of these terms in G.P is also an integer.Then apply formula for sum of terms in G.P. This yields

Some integer = $a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2+a_1r^3+......+a_1r^{n-1}+a_1r^n = a_1 \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

Comment: Please note that $$a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2+a_1r^3+......+a_1r^{n-1}+a_1r^n = a_1 \large{\frac{1-r^{n\color{red}+1}}{1-r}}$$

Comment: @callculus thanks for pointing out typo